# Apex Trigger to update Account field when Case field is updated

Tags: apex, trigger, workflow, account, update

I am struggling to come up with a trigger to update an Account field (Last Survey Sent) when the same field gets inserted or updated on the Case (Last Survey Sent). I am unable to do this via workflow. Any help?

Survey gets sent -> Last Survey Sent field on Case is updated to TODAY() -> Last Survey Sent field on its Account gets set to the same date as the Last Survey Sent field on the Case.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following trigger code to keep the two in sync. Rename the Last Survey Sent to match your API name.

```
Trigger CaseAfterInsertUpdate on Case (after insert, after update) {
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    for (Case c : Trigger.new) {
        Account acc = new Account(
            Id = c.Account.Id,
            Last_Survey_Sent__c = c.Last_Survey_Sent__c
        );
        accList.add(acc);
    }
    try {
        update accList;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('Could not update Last Survey Sent field on Account with cause: ' + ex.getCause())
    }
}
```

And the test class. This assumes that the Last Survey Sent field is writable on the Case object.

```
@isTest
private class CaseTriggerTests() {
    @isTest static void testLastSurveySent() {
        // Insert Account and Case for tests
        // These may need additional fields, depending on your organization
        Account acc = new Account(
           Name = 'Test Account',
           Website = 'www.test.com',
           Phone = '8888888888'
        );
        insert acc;
        Case c = new Case(
            Account = acc.Id,
            Last_Survey_Sent__c = Date.Today();
        );
        insert c;
        // Test that the Last Survey Sent field on the account was updated on Insert
        Account accTest = [SELECT Id, Last_Survey_Sent__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.id];
        System.assertEquals(accTest.Last_Survey_Sent__c, Date.Today());
        // Test that the Last Survey Sent field on the account changes on Update
        c.Last_Survey_Sent__c = Date.Today()+1;
        update c;
        accTest = [SELECT Id, Last_Survey_Sent__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.id];
        System.assertEquals(accTest.Last_Survey_Sent__c, Date.Today()+1);
    }
}
```

While it may seem more intuitive to query for the account, the use of `new` and then setting the ID protects you during bulk updates. If you had 1000 cases to update at once, it would require 1000 SOQL queries. Also note that I am adding the accounts to a list and updating the entire list after the trigger runs its `for` loop. That's another technique for 'bulkifying' and protects against exceeding DML  limits.

Let me know if you have any other questions. I would be happy to walk you through writing unit tests for this trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would be more than happy if you could help with the apex class/unit tests.

Comment: Sure thing. Added test into original answer.

Comment: Case c = new Case(
            Account = acc.Id,
            Last_Survey_Sent__c = Date.Today();
 );    Is Account supposed to be Id in the above code?

Comment: That is setting the Account that the Case is tied to.

Comment: Now I am getting "assertion failed, expected null" even though the query was added when testing the field on Insert. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with point and click I would check into using visual flow. [Here](http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf) is a guide if you haven't used it before. [Here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wYVIEA2) is a sample pack as well. Otherwise I would look into a trigger on the case object, a similar question/answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260613/trigger-to-copy-image-from-child-record-to-parent-record).

Comment: Thanks for the help Jenny. I plan on using a apex trigger as not only can I learn more on using triggers but it is the easiest solution outside of a workflow for me.